# UITableView Not Showing Second Instance of Custom Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am creating a form using a dynamic UITableView, custom UITableViewCells, and the built-in Right Detail cell. My tableview has 3 sections. The tableview does not render the second occurrence of any of my custom cells, but it does render the first occurrence. Identifiers for my custom cells are textFieldCell and switchCell. The use of a custom cell at section 0 row 0 renders fine, but the next reference to the cell at section 1 row 0 just presents an empty cell. The custom cell at section 2 row 0 only shows once as well. The other reference to this custom cell is also empty. The built-in cell title fieldDisplayCell renders fine each time it is called.

Does anyone know the reason why the tableview is not rendering the second reference to the custom cell? The cellForRowAt function I am using is pasted below.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //Setup the first section
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "textFieldCell", for: indexPath) as? TextFieldCell else {return UITableViewCell()}
            cell.configureCell(withPlaceHolder: "Title")
            return cell
        } else {
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "fieldDisplayCell", for: indexPath) as? FieldDisplayCell else {return UITableViewCell()}
            cell.configureCell(withFieldLabel: "Type", andValueLabel: "Date")
            return cell
        }
    }

    //Setup the second section
    if indexPath.section == 1 {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "textFieldCell", for: indexPath) as? TextFieldCell else {return UITableViewCell()}
            cell.configureCell(withPlaceHolder: "Location")
        } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "fieldDisplayCell", for: indexPath) as? FieldDisplayCell else {return UITableViewCell()}
            cell.configureCell(withFieldLabel: "Start", andValueLabel: "June 17, 2018")
            return cell
        } else {
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "fieldDisplayCell", for: indexPath) as? FieldDisplayCell else {return UITableViewCell()}
            cell.configureCell(withFieldLabel: "End", andValueLabel: "June 17, 2018")
            return cell
        }

    }

    //Setup the third section
    if indexPath.section == 2 {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "switchCell", for: indexPath) as? SwitchCell else {return UITableViewCell()}
            cell.configureCell(withFieldLabal: "Remind")
            return cell
        } else {
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "switchCell", for: indexPath) as? SwitchCell else {return UITableViewCell()}
            cell.configureCell(withFieldLabal: "Track")
        }
    }

    return SwitchCell()
}
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint.  Step through.  See what your code is doing.

Comment: BTW - get rid of those `guard let` when creating the cells. Just use a forced-cast (`as!`) to the proper cell type. You want that code to crash, not return an empty cell if you have things setup incorrectly during development.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you don’t return the cells at section 1 row 0 and section 2 row 1.

So, you have to add `return cell` at these rows.

**At section 1 row 0:**

```
if indexPath.row == 0 {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "textFieldCell", for: indexPath) as? TextFieldCell else {return UITableViewCell()}
    cell.configureCell(withPlaceHolder: "Location")
    return cell
}
```

**At section 2 row 1:**

```
else {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "switchCell", for: indexPath) as? SwitchCell else {return UITableViewCell()}
    cell.configureCell(withFieldLabal: "Track")
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you override numberOfRowsInSection and numberOfSections functions?
Without which, tableView will not know how many rows or sections you want to be rendered:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch (section)
    {
      case 0: return 2
      case 1: return 2
      case 2: return 2
      default: return 2
    }
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 3
}
```